# Difference Between joint probability distribution and conditional probability distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can someone explain to me the difference between joint probability distribution and conditional  probability distribution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Broadly speaking, joint probability is the probability of two things* happening together: e.g., the probability that I wash my car, *and* it rains.  Conditional probability is the probability of one thing happening, given that the other thing happens: e.g., the probability that, given that I wash my car, it rains.

Consider the space of all four combinations:

- I wash my car, and it rains.
- I wash my car, and it doesn't rain.
- I don't wash my car, and it rains.
- I don't wash my car, and it doesn't rain.

Quantitatively, the difference is that in the case of joint probability, we evaluate across the space of all four combinations: The joint probability is the the first, divided by the sum of all four.  (Note: If we're talking about a probability space, the sum of all four is everything—i.e., it has probability one.)

In the case of conditional probability, we only examine those cases where I wash my car (the antecedent).  So the conditional probability is the first, divided by the sum of the first two.

*More than two things could be involved.  But the basic idea can most clearly be illustrated with two things.

Answer (score 3):

I will answer this question with a typical example as it might be easier to understand the difference, but first for some definitions:

`Definition 1:`

Given two independent events $A$ and $B$ $$P(A \space\mathrm{and}\space B)=P(A)\times P(B)=\space$$The probability of event $A$ *and* event $B$ happening simultaneously. This is known as $\color{#180}{\fbox{Joint Probability}}$

---

`Definition 2:`

$$P(A\mid B)=\cfrac{P(A \space\mathrm{and}\space B)}{P(B)}=\space$$The probability that event $A$ occurs **given** that event $B$ has occurred. This is  $\color{#F80}{\fbox{Conditional Probability}}$.

> The following table gives data on the type of car, grouped by petrol
>   consumption, owned by $100$ people.
>
> $$\begin{array}{|c|l:l|}\hline  & \mathsf{Low} & \,\mathsf{Medium} &
>  \,\mathsf{High}& \,\mathbf{Total} \\ \hline \mathsf{Male} & 12 & 33 &
>  7  \\ \hdashline \mathsf{Female} & 23 & 21 & 4   \\ \hdashline   &  &
>  & & 100 \\ \hline \end{array}$$
>
> One person is selected at random.
>
> Let $L$ be the event "the person owns a low rated car"
>
> Let $F$ be the event "a female is chosen".

`Questions:`

Find

i). $P(L)=\space$The probability of selecting someone with a low rated car,

ii). $P(F \space\mathrm{and}\space L)=\space$The probability of selecting a female with a low rated car.

iii). $P(F\mid L)=\cfrac{P(F \space\mathrm{and}\space L)}{P(L)}=\space$The probability of selecting a female given the car is low rated.

`Solutions:`

i).

$$\begin{array}{|c|l:l|}\hline
 & \mathsf{Low} & \,\mathsf{Medium} & \,\mathsf{High}& \,\mathbf{Total} \\
\hline
\mathsf{Male} & \color{blue}{12} & 33 & 7  \\ \hdashline
\mathsf{Female} & \color{blue}{23} & 21 & 4 
 \\ \hdashline
  &  \color{red}{35}& & & \color{red}{100} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
$$P(L)=\frac{12+23}{100}=\frac{35}{100}=\frac{7}{20}$$

ii). $$\begin{array}{|c|l:l|}\hline
 & \mathsf{Low} & \,\mathsf{Medium} & \,\mathsf{High}& \,\mathbf{Total} \\
\hline
\mathsf{Male} & 12 & 33 & 7  \\ \hdashline
\mathsf{Female} & \color{red}{23} & 21 & 4 
 \\ \hdashline
  &  & & & \color{red}{100} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
$$P(F \space\mathrm{and}\space L) = \cfrac{23}{100}$$ This is the joint probability and is the probability that two events happen simultaneously, note that this is sometimes written $P(F \cap L)$ which is known as the intersection of events $F$ and $L$.

iii). We need to be careful with the denominators in ii). and iii). Here we are given that the car is low rated; so we want the total of that column: $$\begin{array}{|c|l:l|}\hline
 & \mathsf{Low} & \,\mathsf{Medium} & \,\mathsf{High}& \,\mathbf{Total} \\
\hline
\mathsf{Male} & \color{blue}{12} & 33 & 7  \\ \hdashline
\mathsf{Female} & \color{blue}{23} & 21 & 4 
 \\ \hdashline
  &  \color{red}{35} & & & 100 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$P(F\mid L)=\cfrac{23}{35}$

It's helpful to notice that from the definition of conditional probability: $P(L)\times P(F\mid L)=\cfrac{7}{20}\times\cfrac{23}{35}=\cfrac{23}{100}=P(F \space\mathrm{and}\space L)$ as calculated in part ii).

---

Just one small note: When I put "events $A$ and $B$ happen simultaneously" the word 'simultaneously' is not essentially describing time; it is just a word we use to state that both events happen at once.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful. After reading this, I got a new doubt. What exactly does the independence of 2 events mean? My teacher told me that it is not merely the meaning of the English language but mathematically it represents something much more. What is that?

Comment: @user297048 Okay, mathematically $\mathrm{P}(A \cap B) = \mathrm{P}(A)\times\mathrm{P}(B)$ if and only if the 2 events are independent. In words this means that the __Joint Probability__ $\left(\mathrm{P}(A \cap B)\right)$ is equal to the product of the two events $\left(\mathrm{P}(A)\times\mathrm{P}(B)\right)$ but this is only true if and only if the occurrence of event $A$ does not affect the probability of the other (event $B$). See [Independence(probability theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) for more information on this. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

How can you apply the first equation in the above, i.e. $P(F \, \text{and} \,  L)=P(F)*P(L)$? $P(F)=12/25$, $P(L)=7/20$, then the product is $28/125$ which is different from $23/100$ ? What mistake did I make here?